# How datacards receive value from listbox

Tags: powerapps

I have two screens in powerapps, one is 'Port of Loading' and another is 'Editscreen1' for survey usage.

In 'port of loading', it will have a list of value in listbox3 which can pass the value to 'editscreen1' datacardvalue10.
`Navigate(EditScreen1,ScreenTransition.None, {DataCardValue10:ListBox3.SelectedItems})`

But my datacardvalue10 canot receive data from listbox3, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t set an item directly. Instead, try:

```
Navigate( 
  YourPage,
  YourTransition,
  {
    ValueForCard: Gallery.selected
  }
)
```

You data card should contain the ValueForCard variable as the default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, found that the field from datacard cannot get the value, if I use a textbox then I can use the formula similar to your answer to do my job. Thanks for your help.